# error while reading excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the below code to get data from excel file. While opening the connection I get the below error. can any one tell me how can I solve this issue?

**Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.**

Note: ExcelFilePath is the path of excel file stored in local drive.

```
String connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", ExcelFilePath);

 DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

            DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            connection.Open(); // GIVES ERROR 

            DataTable tbl = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

            connection.Close();

            foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
            {
                //get sheets.

            }
```

Comment: Actually its a sharepoint web application project

Comment: Can you give full description of error(Stacktrace)?

Comment: @Dany, Stacktrace:  at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()

Comment: and the Coonection String is "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=http://sharepoint server/ExcelFiles/Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"

Comment: Whether your problem is solved or not? I edited my answer.Check it.

Comment: @Dany, I am working with sharepoint sandboxed solution. so where do i have to set the PERMISSION_SET? Also I am using Oledbconnection to get data from excel file stored in server. I have not used any database in the project.Can you please tell me how can i fix this permission error?

Comment: Hi, I have not worked on Sharepoint ...But you can get the details of permission Set on http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=533

Answer (score 2):

This error is normally caused by code access security. Try to run your application in full trust mode.

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

Comment: where do i have to give full trust? My project does not have web.config file

Comment: I am afraid that you need to have some sort of share point admin privilege for this. This article may give you some details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583158(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 32 bit system then config file is at location

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\CONFIG`

If you are using 64 bit system then config file is at location

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\{version}\CONFIG`

Try this.

The exception you encountered indicates that the C# assembly containing the stored procedure that you registered has insufficient permissions to create an OleDbConnection object, with respect to the .Net framework Code Access Security (CAS) policies. This probably means that your assembly was registered WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE, which is also the default if PERMISSION_SET is unspecified in the CREATE ASSEMBLY DDL statement.

To fix this, you can re-register your assembly WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS to gain access to the ADO.Net classes (including OleDbConnection). If you are using Visual Studio, you will have to make this change from SAFE to EXTERNAL_ACCESS in the properties page of your C# database project.

For More Details Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x4t63kb.aspx

Comment: Hi..thasnks  I have used .net framework 3.5 in my application. and in the folder %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\{version}\ where version is v3.5 i canr find config and any config files. any ideas?

Comment: Actually there is config Folder and that folder contains config file. But whether you are using 32 bit or 64 bit system?

Comment: Is that folder (Framework) is empty or it contains some another folder?

Comment: the path is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5" but i dont find any config file inside this. Can you tell me what is the exact name of config file?

Comment: The name of config file is "Web.config" .There may be condition like that you are using framework 3.5 but your machine contains framework 4.0. So the config folder will be at location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0."

Comment: I have checked the web config file present in .net 4 framework..but trust level is already set to Full. <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />